# Elasticsearch 5.4, Is there a way not set the document type when doing search?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

What I'm trying to do now is I would like to search two document types in two indices. But in C#, Nest, you need you add a type  in the search function like this "Client.Search". Since there are different types when search this type on the other indices gives no result set. Is there a way to search in the following endpoint? 
http://ess01:9200/indexa,indexb/_search
Notice that no type is set. I tried to fire a query to the above endpoint and it works well. But I could not find a way to do it in C#. Any idea will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at the .Net NEST client https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/covariant-search-results.html
This is a good article for this issue.